# How to identify notesView columns that have column totals defined for them?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have several views that have 'column totals' defined in some columns of these views. The totals can be in different positions in each view. I'm looking a for a fast, reliable way of identifying which columns have totals before I scan these columns and views.

**Ideally, I want a 'isTotal' property on the column defintion (NotesViewColumn), but that property is not defined/available.**

I can see that totals in the ColumnValues array does return a 'double' datatype where a column exists, but I can only see this once I've started scanning the data in the view, and I want this detail before I start looking at the data. (For information, the ColumnValues for a category notesViewEntry is an array containing: strings for cat columns, 'empty' for untotalled fields, and doubles for totals).

I can (of course) hard-code this detail somewhere, but it seems archaic to have to do this. I can 'getFirstDoc' to work out the ColumnValues in a 'pre-loop' check, but this seems 'wasteful'.

PS: I have seen something called 'ColumnValuesIndex' but this appears to be an undocumented feature which I would prefer not to use. However, if there were an 'isTotal' undocumented feature - I'd be ok with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined in the original post, looking at the ColumnValues of a NotesViewEntry (NVE) on a category row does provide an array of values you can use to determine if any specific column is either a category string, empty, or a total. The totals have a datatype of double so stepping over the columns in a loop can easily flag the totals.

If the view has categories, then the first NVE in the view will give these details. A simple 'NotesView.GetFirstEntry().ColumnValues' will return the array. If the view has totals, but not categories, you can 'GetLastEntry' for the totals row at the bottom of the view.

Reading the totals is then just a case of looking for category rows (nve.IsCategory) and extracting the totals from the nve.ColumnValues.

Performance is reasonable and can be made a bit quicker by building a booleans array pre-loop of where the totals exist.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of to do this before you scan the data is to export the view design to DXL, then check the DXL for attributes or elements that specify whether each column shows totals.
I'm assuming view columns in DXL have an attribute or child element for this purpose. I haven't checked.

In case you've never done anything like this, using a `NotesDXLExporter` with either a `NotesDOMParser` or a `NotesSAXParser`, you can export selected design elements to in-memory DXL and programmatically analyse it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. DXL extraction is likely to be a lot slower and complicated than examining a single doc's columnsValues 'pre-loop' or reading a pre-calculated DXL summary. Ideally, I just want something simple that can be checked dynamically just before these views are scanned.